# Tomcat Deployment shows the below error - Very likely to create a memory leak

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap

SEVERE : The web application [] created  a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator$1]  and a value of type [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator[]]  but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

It shows three sets of such messages with different values and shows Server startup in 23573ms(some time), but never comes up.

Note : The war file is built using maven from Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [Memory Leak Protection](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection) documentation on the Tomcat wiki.